# Add Service Reference is ALWAYS generating xmlserializer and not DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, silverlight-5.0, netdatacontractserializer

i have a service : 
http://chronicpainhostservice2.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc
i consume it in silverlight 5.0 application. and it all worked fine.
However, when i adding this service to  the project using "add service reference" it ALWAYS generating xmlserializer

One more thing - when i try to add it to simple windows application it is generating DataContractSerializer , so the problem is not in the server.

How can i force silverlight to generate DataContractSerializer ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like svcutil try to verify some conditions before using the appropriate Serializer.
here are some details : 
http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2008/03/wcf-datacontractserializer-schema-rules.html

have you tried to force the serializer used by calling manually svcutil : 
svcutil http://chronicpainhostservice2.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc
 /ser:DataContractSerializer